# Buscar postagens no Facebook por Hashtag no formato JSON

Tags: json, api

Como trazer postagens públicas do facebook por determinada hashtag, por exemplo #OlaMundo. Eu preciso que as postagens venham no formato JSON.

Comment: Porque nao lancas uma query no facebok.com?
Depois pegas na source da pagina com a query lancada e listas as postagens ;)

Comment: Eu já fiz isto @Hardcorder, atravéz do endereço: (https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/luto), porém eu preciso que o resultado seja no formato JSON.

Answer (score 1):

O Facebook não disponibiliza recursos para busca de postagens por *tag*, o único tipo de leitura de *posts* encontrada na [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post), é baseada no ID:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{post-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Onde `{post-id}` deve ser o ID da postagem.

Comment: Olá @KaduAmaral o Facebook disponibiliza sim a busca de hashtags porém é feita pelo **hashtag-id** segundo o (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/hashtag)

Comment: Bacana @LucasCastro, não tinha encontrado, mas se não souber o id não adianta nada. :/ Olha [esse link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056688/hashtag-search-in-facebook-api)